# Почему у меня не исчезает это... Visual Studio Code C++

Tags: visual-studio-code

Почему у меня не исчезает это...
Сделал всё, как показано на данном сайте: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_editing-code
[image: То что нужно исправить]

[image: То что я сделал]

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, а почему полноценную IDE не поставить, Visual Studio Community ?  Visual Studio Code это не IDE, а всего лишь редактор.

Comment: Я понимаю, но я хочу компилировать программу через консоль.

Comment: По картинке трудно определить, но можно предположить что в .json определены два одинаковых участка. Один Вы обвели красным, а другой точно такой же выше, сгенерированный по умолчанию.  настройки из этого участка и  применяются  . Но это только предположение.

Comment: То есть удалить верхний участок, если он точно такой же.

Comment: Нет, только один участок кода....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было установить версию MinGW c этого сайта - https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=directory